# How to use existing UV unwrap texture on model

Tags: texturing, uv

I have character model extracted and it has separate diff, normal map textures etc. Is there any way to apply them as they are? Without manual adjustments?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Are you asking about UV unwrapping your model, or combining *diffuse/normal* textures into one material?

Answer (score 0):

If the masks on your textures based off of a texture map that was made from a UV map are different it will not look to good. If you are tiling textures and say you want a different normal under a stone albedo(diffuse) megascan texture, it would work fine, it would just bring a different shape out of the albedo map. However, from the sounds of it, with a character as you are saying, when dealing with UV's the uv mask on the texture maps created from the UV's must match character UV's or it will not look very good.

Comment: I know, I have only UV texture and a model, but I don't have UV map and that's a problem. For example, I have texture of head and UV unwrap perfectly fits it, but with texture of body it's... Kinda fits, but actually doesn't because of parts of body (like legs and hands) that use same parts of texture and I don't know what to to with this. Manual editing is kinda messy. Maybe it's all because of COLLADA file.

Comment: Well, what I would suggest is retexturing parts of it to fit the map that do not match, by lining the part that does fit up to how it should be and then just manipulate the rest.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I just exported rips with NinjaRipper, then converted them into .obj with Noesis and these .obj have matching UV maps. But thank you for your time C: